# How to call a function inside methods when click a button in a Google Maps' InfoWindow?

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building a Google Maps app using Vue. (I use `.vue` instead of single file component)

i have a number of markers on the map and an InfoWindow tie to each of them with this code.

**Markers** section in the `MapComponent.vue`

```
this.markers[layer.lyr_id][node.nod_id] = new google.maps.Marker({
  icon: {
    scaledSize: configuration.marker.icon.scaledSize,
    url: layer.icon_nod_sub_url,
  },
  position: {
    lat: node.lat,
    lng: node.lon,
  },
  map: mapCanvas,
});
```

**InfoWindow** section in the `MapComponent.vue`

```
this.infoWindows[layer.lyr_id][node.nod_id] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: `<strong>${node.dflt_name}</strong>
            <p>${node.dflt_info}</p>
            <button v-on:click="this.addToPath(${node.nod_id})">Add this node to the path</button>`,
});
```

**EventListener** section in the `MapComponent.vue`

```
this.markers[layer.lyr_id][node.nod_id].addListener('click', () => {
  this.infoWindows[layer.lyr_id][node.nod_id].open(
    mapCanvas,
    this.markers[layer.lyr_id][node.nod_id]
  )
});
```

---

What I'm struggling right now is how to make the `<button>` in the InfoWindow section calls a function defined in the `methods` which looks like this

```
methods: {
  ...
  addToPath(nod_id) {
    alert(nod_id)
    console.log(nod_id)
  }
  ...
}
```

Right now when I click the button it does absolutely nothing, no warning, no error at all.

What should I do to get it work?

---

**Note:**

I have searched and found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202059/how-to-trigger-a-function-using-click-inside-infowindow-of-google-maps-in-vue-j). However, it doesn't work for my case because I use [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44636586/10818714) to import *(which it would be too late to change the way to import)*. When I use the solution in that question, I got the error that says `TypeError: vm is undefined`. So it didn't help me.

---

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a Vue JS component method from outside the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682651/call-a-vue-js-component-method-from-outside-the-component)

Comment: @MelMacaluso I don't get it. How should I do that with module `.vue` files? Where should I put the `document.getElementById()` and the `vm`? I'm really new to Vue, hope this won't be too much trouble.

Comment: Wherever you registered your Vue instance assign it to a constant as specified. Then wherever you call your component just add a ref. Then outside vue wherever you use write your js code you reference it as indicated. Try and let us know how it goes editing your answer.

Comment: @MelMacaluso I have tried the method from the thread you gave, however, the situation is quite different. Mine is more like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fakezcmp/1/), which of course isn't working.

What should I put in the `onclick=""` to make it work? (Seems like doing `document.getElementById()` wouldn't work well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign vue to a constant such as

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { 'map-component': MapComponent }
});
```

I then usually assign a ref to it:

```
<map-component ref="map-component">...</map-component>
```

And then you can all the methods inside the component with

```
vm.$refs.map-component.addToPath()
```